# Windows Performance Analyzer Time stamp formatting

Tags: windows, performance, logging, etw, event-viewer

How do i get time stamps for Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power provider from Windows performance recorder. i see Windows performance analyzer gives me a some formatted time but not the exact time stamp.Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean, how do i decode the time shown in Window Performance Analyzer to hh:mm:ss:msms:usus:nsns ( till nano seconds )

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d81bec6d-f5a7-4956-b944-435d564b650c/getting-absolute-wallclock-times-when-analyzing-a-trace-with-windows-performance-analyzer?forum=wptkv5)

> WPA offers the timestamp of the trace in Trace -> System Configuration -> Traces -> Start Time (UTC and Local time), which corresponds to time zero (0 ms).

You will have to add the time in seonds to the initial time defined in there